# Interpretation of Cox regression with time varying covariates

Tags: survival, cox-model, time-varying-covariate

After fitting my model to a time varying cox regression, let's say I have a continuos variable $ X $. The hazard ratio of this variable will be higher than 1 (about 2 and it is significantly significant). Is it safe to say that an increase in $ X $ will increase the risk by a factor of two ?

I'm not so sure about this, because this is a time varying covariates.

Comment: I agree with Maarten. Using time-dependent covariates allows for specification of individuals going from one hazard level to another during follow-up. I.e individuals are allowed to jump between hazard levels during specific time-intervals. It does not affect the interpretation of the hazard ratio for that variable. HR of 2 equals two times as great a risk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem with that conclusion. In fact, I would say it is especially meaningful for time varying covariates. Think of a time constant covariate like sex: would someone ever experience what happens if she became a he or the reverse (ignoring sex-change operations)? So time-constant covariates are basically group comparisons, but you would not expect someone to experience such a change in group membership. In case of time-varying covariates it is usually realistic for a person to experience such a change (how else could it vary over time?).